# Is it possible to search in bubble chart with dc.js

Tags: dc.js

Can we search in bubble chart using dc.js

[image: bubble seacrh]

We have a dropdown box  like this:

```
<select name="dbox" id="dbox" multiple="true">
<option value="3200">3200</option>
....
</select>
```

Here I tried jquery function:

```
function multiple_filter(dim,selectionArray){

        if (selectionArray!==null) {
            dim.filter(function(d) { 
            return selectionArray.indexOf(d) >= 0; });

        } else {
        return dim.filter(null);

        }
        dc.redrawAll();
 }
```

When we want to filter dimension here applying function:

```
$("select#dbox").on("change",function(){

    var val=$(this).val();
    multiple_filter(dboxDimension,val);

});
```

This works but main filtering dimension doesnt filter.

So How can we change function to draw main filtering dimension ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's not so much a matter of filtering the bubble chart as applying a filter externally.  I'm going to flag as a duplicate, since this has been answered before, but please comment if this doesn't suit your purpose.

Comment: Infact I want to filter with multiple selection with select options.Not only text

Comment: Also this filtering couldnt filter which main filtering chart

Comment: When we use text box we can only one text filter.But When we use select box with multiple selection we should filter with multiple selection.So I wanto to use filter with dropdown selection with multiple

Comment: OK Gordon.I revised the question

Comment: Hmm, I was going to suggest [this PR](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/771) but I guess they haven't gotten to the multiple selection part yet. Guess you will have to code it by hand. It's not that hard....

Comment: Gordon I edited my question and added new multiple_filter function.But there is another problem.Please look at this.Thanks

Comment: Now, what do you mean by main filtering dimension?  A different chart's dimension?  Please revise your question again.  This code looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to create a new "graph" textFilterWidget, it can even allow you to search on data that aren't displayed on the bubble chart (eg longer name...)

(you need to use a different dimension (well, you can have a different one that has the same function/data) than the one from the bubble, otherwise weird stuff will happen)